# TCP Connection through IP Addresses & Port in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

We're trying to establish a TCP connection in Python 3.8, where we want each machine to become a client and a server at the same time, so that each machine can send and receive messages. With this code, we can send and receive data (sometimes), but we have noticed that each machine can send messages to the first ip address in the `IPs` list, but the rest are neglected.

Perhaps there's a better way than this to establish a TCP Connection, so we can send data to each other?

All three sections (*Server, Client & Sharing Distribution*) of codes are attached to a python program that each machine is running.

**Start Distribution:**

Here server socket is initiated, and we start threads for each ip-address we want to connect to.

```
def start_distributed_sharing(self):
    self.serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.serv.bind(('0.0.0.0', 44445))
    self.serv.listen(5)
    MAX_CONNECTION = 5
    IPs = ['{ip-address}', '{ip-address}', '{ip-address}', ]

    client_threads = []
    for ip in IPs:
        client_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.client, args=(ip,)))

    for i in range(0, len(client_threads)):
        client_threads[i].start()
    print("Clients is running")

    while True:
        conn, addr = self.serv.accept()
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server, args=(conn, addr,))
        server_thread.start()
        print("New connection to server created!")
```

**Server:**

Each Machine starts their own server, and waits for a client to connect

```
def server(self, conn, addr):
    while True:
        data = ''
        try:
            data = conn.recv(4096)
        except Exception:
            print("Server: Lost a connection... Retrying...")
            time.sleep(5)
            break
        if not data: break
        try:
            data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
            print(data)
        except Exception:
            print("Server: Could not decode message: ", data)
    conn.close()
    print('Server: client disconnected')
```

**Client:**

Here the client attempts to connect to the server with the given ip-addresses

```
def client(self, ip):
    # print(ip)
    self.cli = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while True:
        connected = False
        while not connected:
            try:
                print("Client: Connecting to, ", ip)
                self.cli.connect((ip, 44445))
                connected = True
            except Exception:
                print('Client: Could not connect to: ', ip, '. Retrying...')
                time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                print("Client: Sending a msg to, ", ip)
                self.cli.send(json.dumps({"id": "{PC1}", "height": self.nodes[self.current_leader].node_stats.lastBlockHeight, "latency": self.nodes[self.current_leader].avgLatencyRecords}).encode('utf-8'))
            except Exception:
                print("Client: Could not send more data to, ", ip)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you want only one server for each (machine / program)? In this case, I think you need a unique port for each server. Or if you want each client to behave like a client / server to communicate with the main server, you can use your client's recv method.

Exemple 1 (send message to server and wait response):

```
def client(self, ip):
  self.cli = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  while True:
      connected = False
      while not connected:
          try:
              print("Client: Connecting to, ", ip)
              self.cli.connect((ip, 44445))
              connected = True
          except Exception:
              print('Client: Could not connect to: ', ip, '. Retrying...')
              time.sleep(5)
      while True:
          time.sleep(2)
          try:
              print("Client: Sending a msg to, ", ip)
              self.cli.send(json.dumps({"id": "{PC1}", "height": self.nodes[self.current_leader].node_stats.lastBlockHeight, "latency": self.nodes[self.current_leader].avgLatencyRecords}).encode('utf-8'))
          except Exception:
              print("Client: Could not send more data to, ", ip)
              break

          # Waiting for server response
          response  = self.cli.recv(1024)
```

Now if you want a server message event, you can create a message handler like this (it is not very clean code it is for the example):

```
def on_message(self, msg):
    print(msg)

def message_handle(self):
    while True:
        # Waiting for server message
        msg  = self.cli.recv(1024)
        # check is message if valid
        self.on_message(msg)

def client(self, ip):
    # print(ip)
    self.cli = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    while True:
        connected = False
        while not connected:
            try:
                print("Client: Connecting to, ", ip)
                self.cli.connect((ip, 44445))
                connected = True
            except Exception:
                print('Client: Could not connect to: ', ip, '. Retrying...')
                time.sleep(5)

    # Connection established start message handler
    handler = threading.Thread(target=self.message_handle))
    handler.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            print("Client: Sending a msg to, ", ip)
            self.cli.send(json.dumps({"id": "{PC1}", "height": self.nodes[self.current_leader].node_stats.lastBlockHeight, "latency": self.nodes[self.current_leader].avgLatencyRecords}).encode('utf-8'))
        except Exception:
            print("Client: Could not send more data to, ", ip)
            break
```

In this example, you only had one server and clients on each machine. Then you have to manage the redirection of messages to target clients at the server level (identify the client sending the message and the target clients to address the messages to the right clients).